# In FunctionalJava.List, what does "snoc" mean?

Tags: java, functional-java

FunctionJava's List class has a snoc method that does append:
[snoc](http://functionaljava.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/3.0/javadoc/fj/data/List.html#snoc%28A%29)

The description is as follows:

> Appends (snoc) the given element to this list to produce a new list.

What does the word "snoc" here mean? I have tried to look it up in Wikipedia and as an acronym with no success. Does this mean it is doing some special kind of append?

Edit: Thanks all for pointing me to [cons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons#Lists)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The name snoc is cons backwards.

Hope this helps.

http://jlambda.com/~iop/GraphicsActor2D/doc/g2d/jlambda/List.html

Answer (score 18):

It's "cons" reversed as cons prepends, snoc appends.

cons originates from Lisp, I think.

Comment: is "cons" an acronym for something?

Comment: Yes, the list primitive operators in the original Lisp were called `car`, `cdr` and `cons`.  I believe that `cons` was short for "construct" - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons